# ObjectAnimator not taking Int values?

Tags: android, animation, kotlin, objectanimator

On click, I want to move an ImageView to the center of a button, so I thought I´d take the coordinates of the center and then put those coordinates into Objectanimators which I then start simultaneously from an onClickListener. I thought the code below should do that.

```
    var centerX = (dobutton.left + dobutton.right)/2

    var centerY = (dobutton.top + dobutton.bottom)/2

    var soultoX = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(R.id.soul, "x", centerX).apply {
        duration = 1000
    }

    var soultoY = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(R.id.soul, "y", centerY).apply {
        duration = 1000
    }

    fun soulToButton() = AnimatorSet().apply {
        play(soultoX).with(soultoY)
        start()
    }

dobutton.setOnClickListener {
    [...]
    soulToButton()
    [...]
}
```

On click nothing happens. Any ideas why, and how to fix it?

Edit: I replaced `centerY` and `centerX` in the `soulToX/Y` variables with a variety of numbers. That also had no effect. Still no movement whatsoever on click. It works fine with `ofFloat` and floats, so the problem seems to be with Int values and `ofInt`. I see two possible solutions that I don´t know how to implement: Make it work with Int, or make `centerX` and `centerY` floats. Anyone got Ideas for that?

Comment: Maybe you should use `playTogether(soultoX, soultoY)`?

Comment: I tested replacing `play(soultoX).with(soultoY)` with `playTogether(soultoX, soultoY)`, but it didn´t work either.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use **`AnimatorSet`** for multiple simultaneous transitions, its designed exactly for such cases.

With **`AnimatorSet`** your transition animation could look like this:

```
public void onBtnClick(View btn) {
    AnimatorSet animator = new AnimatorSet();
    View imageView = findViewById(R.id.soul);

    ObjectAnimator x = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView,
            "translationX", imageView.getX(), btn.getPivotX() - imageView.getPivotX());

    ObjectAnimator y = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView,
            "translationY", imageView.getY(), btn.getPivotY() - imageView.getPivotY());

    animator.playTogether(x, y);
    animator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    animator.setDuration(1000);
    animator.start();
}
```

Comment: I already use `AnimatorSet` at `fun soulToButton() = AnimatorSet().apply`, I´m just trying to get the right coordinates in the right format, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about your animation value is correct, perhaps all you need is to refresh your view try something like `requestlayout` or `invalidate` etc.